# When inserting a row, can the `ParentId` be set as the `Id` from a previous inserted row within the same query?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-insert

Suppose I have a table called `@tblTemp` like this:

```
DECLARE @tblTemp TABLE
                 (
                     Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
                     Name VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
                     ParentId INT NULL
                 )
```

and my XML structure (assigned to `@Xml`) was:

```
<Data>
    <MyRow Name="I am the Parent"/>
    <MyRow Name="I am the child" ParentName="I am the Parent"/>
</Data>
```

**Question**: would it be possible to insert into the `ParentId` column within the same query?

SQL Script

```
INSERT INTO @tblTemp ([Name], [ParentId])
    SELECT
        Rw.value('@Name','VARCHAR(MAX)'), -- Name
        (SELECT [Id]  -- Select ID From Parent Name
         FROM @tblTemp AS [TT] 
         WHERE [TT].[Name] = Rw.value('@ParentName', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))
    FROM 
        @Xml.nodes('Data/MyRow') AS Data(Rw)

SELECT * 
FROM @tblTemp AS [TT]
```

The script inserts `NULL` into the `ParentId` column as I suspect the previous inserts haven't been committed yet so the table will be empty.

Alternative: if it isn't possible to insert into the `ParentId` column within the same query, then my alternative would be to do the insert then update the table where required.

Comment: "I suspect the previous inserts haven't been committed yet so the table will be empty." - you're right. The parent elements don't *get* their `Id` until that `INSERT` statement has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tblTemp TABLE
                 (
                     Id INT NOT NULL,
                     Name VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
                     ParentId INT NULL
                 )
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Data>
    <MyRow Name="I am the Parent"/>
    <MyRow Name="I am the child" ParentName="I am the Parent"/>
    <MyRow Name="another child" ParentName="I am the Parent"/>
    <MyRow Name="baby" ParentName="I am the child"/>
</Data>';

WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT r.value(N'@Name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [Name]
          ,r.value(N'@ParentName',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [ParentName]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNmbr
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Data/MyRow') AS A(r)
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Lvl
          ,[Name]
          ,[ParentName]
          ,RowNmbr
          ,CAST(NULL AS BIGINT) AS ParentRowNmbr
          ,CAST(N'' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ParentPath]
    FROM DerivedTable 
    WHERE ParentName IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.Lvl+1
          ,t.[Name]
          ,t.[ParentName]
          ,t.RowNmbr
          ,r.RowNmbr
          ,r.[ParentPath]+t.[ParentName]+N'|'
    FROM DerivedTable AS t
    INNER JOIN recCTE AS r ON r.[Name]=t.[ParentName]
)
--Use this SELECT to see all columns returned by the recursive CTE
--SELECT * FROM recCTE

INSERT INTO @tblTemp(ID,[Name],ParentId)
SELECT RowNmbr, [Name],ParentRowNmbr
FROM recCTE;

SELECT * FROM @tblTemp;
```

The result

```
Id  Name            ParentId
1   I am the Parent NULL
2   I am the child  1
3   another child   1
4   baby            2
```

Short explanation:

The first CTE will read the values as derived table and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to give a running number to each row as ID.
The second CTE is recursively travelling down the road.
The result can be inserted directly into your table.

**Attention**

I changed your table from `ID is IDENTITY` to a normal INT column. You can use `SELECT MAX(ID)` first to get the highest existing ID and add this to `ROW_NUMBER()` in the first CTE. Otherwise it might happen, that the IDs given by `ROW_NUMBER()` are not the same as the ID given by `IDENTITY`.